# How do I load data when tables names are stored in variables?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to load data from several CSV documents in a database.

The problem is that there is a table for a file, thus the table name has to be stored in a variable progressively updated by the loop. The tables are created, but after that the script fails; Nothing happens, my tables and their fields always have 0 lines.

I think that my idea is feasible, because some topics describe some tips in this way, but nothing works in my case.

This is my code that fails:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO". $name_of_the_file." (id, content) values (". $arrayGenre[0].",'".trim($arrayGenre[1])."')";
```

where `$name_of_the_file` refers to the table created in the loop, referring ultimately to the file targeted by the loop.

---

Following your recommendations, I added a space and print the query by:

```
echo ("<br>". $query);
```

Here is an example for the first line. No offense for the xxx substitutions: these are nominative data.

```
INSERT INTO names.csv (id, url, content) values (1,'xxx_some_adressxxx,'agency: xxx')
```

I do not know enough PHP to say that it is the expected result, but that seems a good SQL request and the values are fine.

Here are the next lines of my script:

```
$mysqli->query($query);
```

and at the beginning of my script, the definition of `$mysqli`:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

---

New edit :

Well it was in fact SQL code which was badly written...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a space:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ". $name_of_the_file ...
```

It's always worth outputting your SQL via `echo` to make sure it looks like what you expect it to look like.

Edit:

```
INSERT INTO names.csv (id, url, content) values (1,'xxx_some_adressxxx,'agency: xxx')
```

You need to add an apostrophe at the end of the second field:

```
INSERT INTO names.csv (id, url, content) values (1,'xxx_some_adressxxx','agency: xxx')
```

I'd also recommend that you look into things like PDO, to make your code more robust and more secure.

You can also try pasting your SQL directly into the database, to see if it gives you an error.

Comment: -1 for the space suggestion. Adding a space won't do anything. +1 for the echo suggestion. Always a good idea when your SQL isn't working as you'd expect to echo out the generated statement.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 - you might want to check and see where I added the space.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought you were adding it at the end of the string concation. Didn't see it after the INTO. +1 for the solution and +1 for the echo. 2 internets for you.

Comment: I edited my question with the result of echo. However there is always 0 result in my database.